# Evaluate function macros and expressions with libclang

Tags: function, macros, libclang

Is it possible to evaluate expressions and function macros with libclang?

Something like this (expression):

```
#define SOMETHING 1 | 2 | 4 | 0x10
```

Or something with a function macro:

```
#define ADD(a,b) a+b
#define THING ADD(10,5)
```

I can tokenize the macro or get its raw text but I don't see any way to evaluate it.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: Nope...I'm using libclang with Ruby and I ended up just using copious amounts of Ruby's eval() to accomplish this

Comment: This isn't a full answer, but using a python wrapper for libclang, I was able to find the macro by setting `clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.PARSE_DETAILED_PROCESSING_RECORD` for the `options` kwarg. This would get me SOMETHING in the first once, but I made function to get the definition part. I haven't also checked if this works for function macros.

Comment: Any chance, @LeoCHan you still have some portion of your solution to share with the community?